# Is there a twisted pair standard for video+power+RS485?

Tags: camera, video-capture, analog, twisted-pair

I am building a PC-based security DVR. I am using Cat6 to carry the video signal (converted via balun), power, and RS-485.

Is there a standard or convention for which twisted pairs I use for which? The baluns I am using are screw terminal so I am free to use any twisted pairs I choose for the video as well as the power and RS-485.

Comment: How much power is going down those lines? Are you following an existing guide for this?

Comment: 12VDC 120mA per cat6 cable

Comment: as for a guide. not per say. I am using commercial grade video baluns specifically meant to be used with cat5/6 cable. Its done all the time, but I haven't yet seen a wiring guide for which twisted pairs are used for power/485/video